# Memory Usage - Large Images

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, tiles

I'm using Tiled to cut up my large images to save memory, but it uses the same amount? My image is 1986 x 1562 pixels in PNG format and that uses up 31MB of memory during gameplay. When I use a tilemap it is 180 x 120 tiles in TMX format and uses 31MB. Am I just doing something wrong? I put the TMX file in my project along with the PNG file.

I don't understand. I will have about 10 images that size in my application. What should I do?

Comment: a good tutorial on this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d

Comment: Are you removing them from the texture cache when you don't need them any more?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am just trying to get it below 20MB. I was hoping the tilemap would do that.

Comment: @Jon, just to be clear. You're not thinking about the file size now, are you? Just thinking because it seems like you want the game to be available for 3G downloading.

Comment: @zebulon, No I wasn't thinking about the file size. I didn't know you could only have a certain size for 3G downloading. I did know that 20MB or over you would have to download the application on WiFi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, any iPhone older than 3GS has a max texture size of 1024x1024. Your game will crash on older devices. Second, OpenGL rounds up the texture size to the nearest power of two when creating textures. Your 1986x1562 textures are actually 2048x2048, which is 4 megs a pop.

That your app uses 31 megs after loading one texture is likely due to other factors. Unless you come back with a blank project that just loads one of those monstrous textures and still you've got 31 megs, I say it's something else.

What you should do is logically group your textures into multiple images of 1024x1024. And use Xcode's profiling tools to determine where the memory is going.